# Is it possible to install Cain and abel in ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I just want to know if it's possible to get Cain and abel installed in ubuntu, it would really help my work instead of dual booting back to my windows 7 just to use it. THanks!

Comment: WineHQ has garbage and bronze reviews... But are you sure that cracking passwords is legal in your country?

Comment: I'm doing it for my own security, i'm testing my security out, and are they helpful? Thanks for the advice man :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Cain and Abel does not have an Ubuntu port, and is not Wine friendly. Still, its functionality is not exclusive. If you wish to complete the same tasks it requires on Ubuntu, you may wish to look into some cross platform alternatives such as John the Ripper or Aircrack. It's likely that you can find a few different programs that will fit your needs.

Comment: I have all of them :/ Cain is the only one i can't install and it happens to be the only one that helps me more with what i'm doing haha, but thanks for the advice though! :D